# Is there anyway to show stopwatch on iOS Lockscreen?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, clock, tweaks

I was wondering is there anyway (app or tweak, jailbreak or normal) to show the currently running stopwatch on the lock screen of iOS device? 
just like an album art and music controls running background.

I've needed this feature recently when was on exam duty as an invigilator because students never stop asking for how much time remaining. Sadly, I had to get my iPhone out of my pocket and enter the pin to answer that.

(It might have been a bit arrogant to show off the awesome 5S.)

Answer (score 1):

There's an app called TimerBar available in Cydia.
It will display a timer in your statusbar at the top.

Source: http://iphonemonsta.com/timerbar-ios-ipad-iphone-stopwatch-cydia-tweak

Comment: Yes, it is a good option yet not compatible with iOS7. And there is another one called "stopur" which I found more accurate for my need and it is not iOS7 compatible too.